# Flink DataSet api with Hbase table input format - read rows multiple times

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.3.2 with the hbase [TableInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-hbase/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/addons/hbase/TableInputFormat.java) from flink-connectors (flink-hbase_2.11), using the DataSet API.

I have an HBase table where the rowkeys are stuctured as follows:

```
| RowKey       | data |
| 0-someuniqid | data |
| 0-someuniqid | data |
| 2-someuniqid | data |
| 2-someuniqid | data |
| 4-someuniqid | data |
| 5-someuniqid | data |
| 5-someuniqid | data |
| 7-someuniqid | data |
| 8-someuniqid | data |
```

The prefix of the table can be 0 to 9 (this is to prevent hot spotting in the hbase nodes). In my test table no one writes to this table.

I have got a job of the form:

```
tableInputFormat0 = new TableInputFormat("table", 0);
tableInputFormat1 = new TableInputFormat("table", 1);
...
tableInputFormat9 = new TableInputFormat("table", 9);


tableInputFormat0.union(tableInputFormat1).(...).union(tableInputFormat9)
                 .map(mapFunction())
                 .rebalance()
                 .filter(someFilter())
                 .groupBy(someField())
                 .reduce(someSumFunction())
                 .output(new HbaseOutputFormat());
```

The problem is when a a lot of records are read (around the 20 million records), the job does not always read the same amount of records.

Most of the time it (correctly) reads: 20,277,161 rows. But sometimes it reads: 20,277,221 or 20,277,171 always more never less. (I get this number via the flink web dashboard, but the effects I can see in what gets written ie too much data is aggregated by the reduce)

I cannot make the problem smaller by using a smaller dataset because the problem does not happen when running the job against a a table of say 5million records. It is hard to identify what records are read multiple times because of the volume.

**How can I debug (and solve) this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

`TableInputFormat` is an abstract class and you have to implement a subclass.

I would do two things:

- check that each input split is processed just once (this info is written to the JobManager log file)
- adapt your input format to count the number of emitted records for each input split. The record count and split id should be written to the (TaskManager) log.

This should help to identify, whether the problem is

- due one (or more) splits being assigned more than once or
- due to a bug in the code that processes a split.